# Random Numbers in \for loop

Tags: foreach, random-numbers

I'm slowly progressing towards understanding the code for creating random arithmetic questions for young students.

At this point, I'm trying to create ten random addition questions.

Why does this not compile? The error message says that `\TenRandomQuestions` is not defined, but I thought I did define it...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand*\initVariables
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{random(0,10)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(0,10)}
}

\newcommand*\OneEquation % This macro compiles.
{
\initVariables
{\newcommand{\answer}{\pgfmathprint{int(\A+\B)}}
$\A+\B=\answer$}
}

\newcommand{\TenRandomQuestions} % This macro does NOT compile. The error message says that this command is undefined.
{%
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,10}%
 {%
 \OneEquation \\   % How do I incorporate \x into this? Or do I not need to?
 }%
}%


\begin{document}

\TenRandomQuestions

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{pgffor}` is missing.

Comment: Wow. Ok, is there a list/explanation of packages related to TikZ and PGF that I should know about?

Comment: I am sure there are questions about this here on TeX.SX already. In doubt, look into `pgfmanual.pdf` (the `tikz` manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand*\initVariables
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{random(0,10)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(0,10)}
}

\newcommand*\OneEquation % This macro compiles.
{
\initVariables
{\newcommand{\answer}{\pgfmathprint{int(\A+\B)}}
$\A+\B=\answer$}
}

\newcommand{\TenRandomQuestions} % This macro does NOT compile. The error message says that this command is undefined.
{%
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,10}%
    {%
        \OneEquation \\   % How do I incorporate \x into this? Or do I not need to?
    }%
}%


\begin{document}

    \TenRandomQuestions

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `pgffor`ce is strong in you ;-) (+1)

Comment: haha.  You should be getting the credit since you got here first, but it's answer the unanswered questions time.... ;-)

Comment: I don't need the rep  (any longer, my 'hunt' is over) ... and you've misunderstood 'answer the unanswered', that's more for older questions :D

Comment: Indeed, I did not know that.

Comment: Older questions give Revival and Necromancer badges (and rep, of course), that's the reason ;-)

Comment: More than a few days, I would say. Revival badges for first answers after 30 days with 2 votes (so even if there's an older answer, you could get the badge, if your answer gets two votes first), and Necromancer badges for any answer given after 60 days, having  5 votes then (whenever the 5 votes are completed)